# Microsoft CRM User Default Form Query

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

We're using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 on-premise. Is there a way to do a database query on the default form that users will see for a specific entity?

The reason I ask, we have a user that has an error when opening an email form:
systemform With Id = a7415a93-0113-4d90-80cd-280e28dfb4f7 Does Not Exist

This might have been an old form that has long been deleted from our system, and I'm wondering if there are any other users that might have this default systemform ID, as it will prevent them from opening that entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users' most recently viewed forms are stored in the `UserEntityUISettingsBase` table. You can query the `UserEntityUISettings` view to see if any users are having the given form as their default form:

```
SELECT * FROM UserEntityUISettings 
WHERE LastViewedFormXml LIKE '%a7415a93-0113-4d90-80cd-280e28dfb4f7%'
```

Keep in mind that it is entirely unsupported to update the database directly, so I would strongly recommend that you only stick to querying. If you find any forms this way, you should change them in a supported manner.

Comment: Thank you this answers it! Do you might know if there's any documentation about CRM user interface specific information that we can access from the database table such as this?

Comment: I am not aware of such information. The CRM database in general is undocumented, since we should be using APIs for accessing data instead (only not all data is exposed via APIs)